# Panel that holds Action and State in Flipper Redux Debugger disappears

Tags: react-native, react-redux, flipper

I am using Flipper 0.189.0. I was able to get the Redux Debugger plugin working, including the panel on the right showing Actions and State properly from my react native app's redux store.

However, whenever there is any activity from the app, or even if I just press the 'Clear' button next to the search box in the middle pane, that rightmost pane disappears. And the only way to get it back is to quit and re-run Flipper.

Has anyone else experienced this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've just discovered that the behavior looks the same as if you've clicked the button in the lower left called 'Right Sidebar Toggle', except the button is then dimmed and clicking it doesn't restore the right sidebar. There's then no way to inspect the redux state until you restart Flipper.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was happening. If no item is selected in the log pane of the Redux Debugger plugin in Flipper, the right sidebar goes away. If you click on any item in the log pane, the right sidebar comes back.

I had hoped that by having no item selected in the log pane, the state pane would show realtime state updating, like in the Chrome redux debugger I'm used to. But this is apparently not the case.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).